# Is there a function in haskell working like a mixture of accumArray and foldr?

Tags: arrays, haskell, fold

let me call the function accumrArray.

```
accumrArray :: 
              (e' -> e -> e) An accumulating function
           -> e              A default element 
           -> (i, i)         The bounds of the array 
           -> [(i, e')]      List of associations 
           -> a i e          The array

accumrArray  (:) [] (1,2) [(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)]  === array [(1,[1]), (2,[2,3])]
head $ (accumrArray (:) [] (1,1) [(1,x)|x<-[4..]]) ! 1 === 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How strange... I wrote this function a few days ago for someone else.  The function first appeared in LML (I believe), but never made it into the Haskell array library.

Here you go:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Array
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.IORef
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.Base
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IO

accumArrayR :: forall a e i. Ix i => (a -> e -> e) -> e -> (i,i) -> [(i,a)] -> Array i e
accumArrayR f e bounds@(l,u) assocs = unsafePerformIO $ do
  ref <- newIORef assocs
  arr <- newArray_ bounds
  let _ = arr :: IOArray i e
  let n = safeRangeSize (l,u)
  let elem x = unsafePerformIO $ do
                  ass <- readIORef ref
                  let loop [] = writeIORef ref [] >> return e
                      loop ((y,a):rest) = do
                         let ix = safeIndex bounds n y
                         let r = f a (elem x)
                         unsafeWrite arr ix r
                         if (ix == x)
                            then writeIORef ref rest >> return r
                            else loop rest
                  loop ass
  forM_ [0..n] $ \ix -> unsafeWrite arr ix (elem ix)
  unsafeFreeze arr
```

A challenge for the reader: use `accumArrayR` to implement linear-time depth-first-search of a graph.

**Edit** I should mention that the function isn't thread-safe as written.  Turning the `IORef` into an `MVar` would fix it, but there might be better ways.

Comment: googling up lml and accumArray brought me to this bit of mailing-list history from '93: http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg01394.html

Comment: Am I the only one that raised an eyebrow at `loop ass`?

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but...
`accumrArray f x b l = accumArray (flip f) x b (reverse l)`

Comment: but it can't handle the infinite list(l)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that

```
accumrArray f x b l = accumArray (flip f) x b (reverse l)
```

is indeed the best solution (credits to sclv's answer).

Its supposed "inefficiency" comes from fact that `foldr` applies the function `f` from right to left.

However, since `accumArray` is strict, `l` can never be infinite, otherwise the program would be incorrect. It would never terminate.

Therefore, `foldl (flip f)` is just as good as a `foldr`.